# python image processing CNN

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-imaging-library, neural-network

I'm trying to write a basic CNN(cellular neural network) in python according to the equation dx/dt = -x + sigma(A*y) + sigma(B*u) + bias and y = f(x). It works as shown in the figure of this [link](http://www.isiweb.ee.ethz.ch/haenggi/CNN_web/architecture.html).Unfortunately,my program doesn't work properly. I used the edge detection template but what I've got was just a darker grayscale image!I just can't figure out where the problem is...Here are some codes:

```
gray = img.open('lena.bmp').convert('L')     #gray1 = rgb2gray(img1)
u = np.array(gray.convert('F'))              #grayscale to float
m,n = gray.size                              #get size
z  = u.copy()                                #copy u

def deriv(x, t):                             #derivertive func of x
    x = np.reshape(x,(m,n))                    
    dx = -x + Ib + Bu + Ay
    return np.reshape(dx,m*n)

for s in range(5):
    Bu = sig.convolve2d(u,tempB,'same')          #get sigma(B*u)
    y = func.fs(z)                               #get output y
    Ay = sig.convolve2d(y,tempA,'same')          #get sigma(A*y)

    z   = np.reshape(z,m*n)                      #reshape z to 1-D array
    z   = sint.odeint(deriv, z, time)            #integrate dx/dt
    z   = np.reshape(z[2,:],(m,n))               #reshape z to mxn array
    plt.imshow(z)
    plt.show()
```

Many thanks.

Comment: Could you please indent your code properly so we can see what is inside the `for` and what isn't.

Comment: After I have put the image values into the range(-1,1), it seems that it works. I think I'm on the right track again.